# How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, typeerror, discord.js

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int.

```
function play(connection, message){
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

                server.queue.shift();

                server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                    if(server.queue[0]){
                        play(connection, message);
                    }else {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                })



            }
```

The error message I'm getting from the tester is:

```
    TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int
    TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int
    Error: "abort(TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info."
    at (anonymous) (file:///c:/Users/pc/Documents/Discord%20Bot/node_modules/opusscript/build/opusscript_native_wasm.js:8:1741) 
    at emit (events.js:311:19)
```

I'm begging you, please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: can we have the full error trace?

Comment: what do you mean "the full error trace?" because that's all debug console shows me.

Answer (score 1):

I may have a solution for your problem!

## UPDATE:

Following this answer and my bug report, **prism-media** released a fixed version. Thank you for such a quick solution! Keeping the text below just as a reference.

### TL;DR

Find Opus.js in `node_modules` folder and go to line 55. You should see the following:

```js
return this.encoder.encode(buffer, Opus.name === 'opusscript' ? null : this._options.frameSize);
```

**CHANGE IT TO:**

```js
return this.encoder.encode(buffer, this._options.frameSize);
```

Then delete the same part at line 59.

### Explanation

1. The exception is thrown in `toWireType` in opusscript_native_wasm.js which expects its second argument to be an int, but it gets a `null`. Hence, the exception.
2. Tracing it back, `toWireType` is called by `OpusScriptHandler.encode` for all its arguments.
3. Those four arguments come from `OpusScript.prototype.encode` in `opusscript.js:69`. The last argument causing the trouble (being `null`) is `**frameSize**.
4. The `encode` function is called from `Opus.js:55` in **prism-media** which is a different module.

```js
return this.encoder.encode(buffer, Opus.name === 'opusscript' ? null : this._options.frameSize);
```

There it is, the `null` causing all the trouble. So the exception is in fact not a fault of the opusscript package.

### Long-term solutions

I [reported the bug](https://github.com/amishshah/prism-media/issues/45) to the module owner, hopefully it gets fixed. *Update: it has been fixed within a few hours! :)*

#### Alternative solution

Using a [custom loader](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3784#issuecomment-586028168) should also work fine. It's still a hack, but more persistent :)